# Remove points separated from bulk

Tags: filtering

I have a set of data coordinate points that add up to the boundary of a simply connected domain, except for some points clearly outside of it, as shown below (the undesirables are inside the red curve), which I wish to remove.

`DeleteAnomalies` as suggested in some posts is not working (in fact, it deletes some of the "good" points).

Moreover, once the data is cleaned, is there an efficient way to generate a (discrete) region from these points that make up the boundary ?

[image]

Comment: Since you were able to encircle the "bad" points, why not use `Select[]` with an appropriate criterion like `Function[{x, y}, (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 >= r^2]`?

Comment: @J.M. True. I would classify a point as anomalous if the distance to the closer legit point is bigger than a threshold, but I don't know a priori what are these legitimate points to compare with.

Comment: For generating a region from boundary points, check the new function [`ReconstructionMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReconstructionMesh.html), introduced in version 13.1.

Comment: @Domen Is there an alternative for earlier versions ? (<12.3)

Comment: Yes, there is a resource function [NonConvexHullMesh](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NonConvexHullMesh).

Comment: @Domen Not quite. NonConvexHullMesh needs the points to be in the bulk, not just in the boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a fairly dense boundary, and the anomalous points seem to lie quite far away. Therefore, you can remove the points for which the distance to its nearest point is more than some manually-defined threshold. Moreover, you can demand that the $n$ closest points are closer than $\varepsilon$.

Since you didn't provide your data, I will generate some.

```
points = N@CirclePoints[200]~Join~RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, 3/2], 50];
eps = .05;
n = 3;

boundary = 
  Select[points, 
   pt |-> And @@ (EuclideanDistance[pt, #] < eps & /@ 
       Take[SortBy[points, EuclideanDistance[pt, #] &], n])];

anomalous = Complement[points, boundary];

ListPlot[{anomalous, boundary}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Boundary]

To generate a mesh, you can sequentially choose the closest point, and connect them into a polygon. This will, however, cut the sharp cusps.

```
reconstructRegion[pts0_] := 
 Module[{pts = pts0[[2 ;;]], poly = {}, nextPoint = pts0[[1]]},
  While[Length@pts > 1,
   nextPoint = SortBy[pts, EuclideanDistance[nextPoint, #] &][[1]];
   AppendTo[poly, nextPoint];
   pts = DeleteCases[pts, nextPoint];
   ];
  Polygon[poly~Join~pts]
  ]
Show[RegionPlot@reconstructRegion[boundary], 
 ListPlot[boundary, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image: Region]

Comment: Thanks !! In the reconstruction, do the points have to be ordered ? It seems that yes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. ``reconstructRegion`` takes any set of points, they do not need to be ordered.

Comment: I'm using your function on a set point and I got this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Foerls7qAuQzqziWjSyojItriFcEBWUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's an issue that also happens with ListCurvePathPlot and ListLinePlot, that the points have to be ordered.

Comment: If you wish to check it yourself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzHK-JkqzziLW1ykUMDt0-fJckRTdJgf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It actually seems to be a problem of the plot, not of the region itself. And it works without problems when discretizing the region. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

`FindShortestTour` work for the `data`.

```
data = RandomSample[data, Length@data];
indexs = FindShortestTour[data] // Last;
reg = Polygon[data[[indexs]]];
Show[Region[reg], Graphics[{Red, Point[data]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great ! Thank you so much. Even though this really helped me I will accept Domen's anwer, as it solves also the first part of my question.